# OpenCV: How to get data in main() from MouseCallback function?

Tags: c++, opencv

I am printing the pixel location on mouse left button click like this:

```
void CallBackFunc(int event, int x, int y, int flags, void* values)
{
     if  ( event == EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN )
     {
          cout << "Left button clicked at (" << x << ", " << y << ")" << endl;
     }


}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{

     Mat img = imread("yava.bmp");
     namedWindow(" Window", 1);
     setMouseCallback(" Window", CallBackFunc, NULL);
     position(x,y); //to be implemneted
     imshow(" Window", img);
     waitKey(0);
     return 0;

}
```

Now I want to get this location, i.e x and y from CallBackFunc to back in main(), which will be processed by my position(x,y) function.

How do i do this?

Comment: Doing something in `main` with data obtained in a callback doesn't make much sense. Put the call to `position` in the callback.

Comment: @chris Shall I have multiple callbacks:   setMouseCallback(" Window", CallBackFunc, position, NULL);..like this?

Comment: @chris can you give an example code to demonstrate what you said?

Comment: If `position` is a regular function, there should be no problem calling it right after you print the stuff in the callback. `if (event == EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN) {cout << …; position(x, y);}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, read the documentation on setMouseCallback, etc.

This is what I would do (this is the typical example) **without changing your code too much**:

```
vector<Point> points; // Store the points as global variables

void CallBackFunc(int event, int x, int y, int flags, void* values)
{
     if  ( event == EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN )
     {
          points.push_back(Point(x,y));

     }


}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{

     Mat img = imread("yava.bmp");
     namedWindow(" Window", 1);
     setMouseCallback(" Window", CallBackFunc, NULL); // Add the pointer to the callback

     while (1)
     {
      //Draw your points
      for (int i=0;i<points.size();i++) circle(img,points.at(i),3,CV_RGB(255,0,0),-1);
      imshow(" Window", img);
      waitKey(10);// -> This is when your callback is called everytime you click
     }
     return 0;

}
```

For a better solution, consider avoiding global variables and use a class for storing those "clicks".

Comment: If doing this, might as well use the nice handy user data parameter instead of a global.

Comment: @chris totally agree, I don' like using globals at all, this just was the simpler solution (without using classes, etc) that came to mind.

Comment: @KeillRandor how do I get the x and y coordinates in main () from points. I put cout<<Mat(points)<<endl; above while loop, but it did not print anything

Comment: No need for a class even, just have a vector in `main` that won't go out of scope and pass `&points`. Just a word of advice to the OP then.

Comment: @user2799508 instead of `circle(img,points.at(i),3,CV_RGB(255,0,0),-1)` write `std::cout << "called in main: " <<  points.at(i) << std::endl`

Comment: @chris you're right, I totally forgot the void* parameter in setMouseCallback and in the callback itself. `points` can be passed through that door.